# Синтаксис функций Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Пытаюсь перенести функцию sql server в postgres
выдает ошибку синтаксиса:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "_count"

по документации вроде правильно написал
 [doc assignment](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT)

```
_count := (SELECT count(score) from   PaperReviewing wh...
```

(Обновлено)вот код целиком, теперь вот здесь ошибка

> syntax error at end of input

и указывает на $$

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SubmitReview(_paper_id INT, _reviewer_id INT, _score INT)
RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
    _mark float; 
    _count INT;
BEGIN
     _mark := 0;
    _count := 0;
    IF Exists(Select paper_id, reviewer_id from PaperReviewing where paper_id=_paper_id and reviewer_id =_reviewer_id )AND _score in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) then
        UPDATE PaperReviewing
            SET score = _score;
           _count := (SELECT count(score) from   PaperReviewing where paper_id = _paper_id );
        If ( _Count)>=3 then
             _mark := cast( (Select sum(score) from PaperReviewing where paper_id = _paper_id) as float)/_Count;
            IF _mark>4 then
                UPDATE Paper
                    SET accepted=1 
                    where Id = @paper_id;
            else 
                UPDATE Paper
                    Set accepted = 0 
                    where Id = @paper_id;
                    end if;
    else 
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Not implemented yet';
END IF;
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Ну и разнобой в регистре же у вас, а от не соответсвий отступов вникать в код просто не хочется. Когда их вообще нет, начинаешь мысленно расставлять, но когда они расставлены не в попад, мозг при попытке разбора просто взрывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А где же код **до** _count := ...? Есть подозрение, что вы точку с запятой в конце предыдущей строки забыли, ровно, как и в этой

```
_count := (SELECT count(score) from   PaperReviewing where paper_id = _paper_id );
```

Вторая ошибка в следствии отсутсвия закрытия одного из ифов. У вас 3 IF и лишь 2 END IF.

Comment: _____благодарю!